# identifying vowels

Tags: vb.net

I have recently found it difficult to identify vowels on my work, which my teacher asked me too do, does anybody have a way of doing it?...currently my code is.

```
Dim mystring As String
Dim isitavowel As Boolean
Dim VOWELCOUNT As Integer

Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the text of your choice here")
    mystring = Console.ReadLine
    VOWELCOUNT = 0
    For i = 1 To mystring.Length

        isitavowel = False
        If mystring(i - 1) = "a" Or mystring(i - 1) = "A" Then isitavowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "e" Or mystring(i - 1) = "E" Then isitavowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "i" Or mystring(i - 1) = "I" Then isitavowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "o" Or mystring(i - 1) = "O" Then isitavowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "u" Or mystring(i - 1) = "U" Then isitavowel = True

        If isitavowel = True Then
            VOWELCOUNT = VOWELCOUNT + 1
        End If


    Next
    Console.WriteLine("That had " & VOWELCOUNT & " vowel's in it")
    Console.ReadLine()
```

The problem is that sometimes it has errors. please help!

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should add the tag 'Homework'

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of regular expressions.

Comment: wait... what do you mean by regular expressions?

Comment: The homework tag has been deprecated.

Comment: RegularExpression is way overkill for something like this.

Answer (score 3):

I optimized the code for you. This should give you a result quick and nice:

```
Private vowels As String = "aeiou"

Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the text of your choice here")
    Dim mystring As String = Console.ReadLine.ToLower
    Dim VOWELCOUNT As Integer = 0

    For Each c As Char In mystring
        If vowels.Contains(c) Then VOWELCOUNT += 1
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("String contained {0} vowels in it", VOWELCOUNT)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

You state you are fairly new to coding so to go through the code:

- In the main we define a string with all the chars we want to identify.
- Then inside the routine we dim initializing it directly from ReadLine as this will return a string.
- We lower-case that string so we can check fewer characters
- Then a for-each loop will go through the string for us, char by char.
- we check if the string containing the vowels contains that char. If it does it will return true.
- If true THEN will allow as to count +1 for the vowels. The short form up here is the same as doing as you did. There is no difference in speed, only simpler to write. Note: in general we don't need to check = true (or = false). we can use the value directly: `If value Then` or `If Not value Then`
- And then we present the result by formatting a string. The {0} takes the first argument we give after comma (a {1} would take the next and so forth).
- by dimming and initializing locally in the routine you could have re-used the routine without resetting the variables (counter in this case).

Answer (score 2):

I have edited and improved upon your code here is my solution you shouldn't get any problems with this one.

```
  Module Module1
    Dim kMyString As String
    Dim kVowel As Boolean
    Dim kVowelNumber As Integer
    Dim kAnswer As Integer = 0
    Sub Main()
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence below:")
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan
        kMyString = Console.ReadLine
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray
        For k = 1 To kMyString.Length
            Console.Write(kMyString(k - 1))
            kVowel = False
            If kMyString(k - 1) = "a" Or kMyString = "A" Then kVowel = True
            If kMyString(k - 1) = "e" Or kMyString = "E" Then kVowel = True
            If kMyString(k - 1) = "i" Or kMyString = "I" Then kVowel = True
            If kMyString(k - 1) = "o" Or kMyString = "O" Then kVowel = True
            If kMyString(k - 1) = "u" Or kMyString = "U" Then kVowel = True

            If kVowel Then
                Console.WriteLine(" is a vowel")
                kAnswer = (kAnswer + 1)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(" isn't a vowel")
            End If
        Next
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed
        Console.WriteLine("There are " & kAnswer & " vowels!")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Kcoded, appreciate you looking over my code, does this count and list the vowels???

Comment: Yes at the end it will display "There are *** vowels" so you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in several ways

- Like you are doing
- Regular expressions (RegEx)
- [LINQ (Language Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397940.aspx)

But because this homework, you will need to read up on the last two, and for now,  I will only help you

```
 For k = 1 To kMyString.Length
    Dim xter = kMyString(k - 1).ToLower  'convert to lowercase
    kVowel = False

    If xter = "a" or xter = "e" or xter = "i" or xter = "o" or xter = "u" Then 
       kVowel = true
       VOWELCOUNT = VOWELCOUNT + 1
    End If
 Next
```

Your code is shorter now. Or as someone suggested

```
For k = 1 To kMyString.Length
    Dim xter = kMyString(k - 1).ToLower  'convert to lowercase

    If InStr("aeiou", xter) > 0 Then  //"aeiou".Contains(xter)
       VOWELCOUNT += 1
    End If
Next
```

### LINQ

This looks like using calculator in exam when you are supposed to show your calculations. Might not be good for assignment but will help you later

```
Dim VOWELCOUNT As Integer = kMyString.Count(Function(v) "aeiou".Contains(v))
```

Comment: Sorry for editing such a new answer... I would have typically let you know about the typo, but I saw it when reviewing a different proposed edit and thought it was an older answer